# Bulk download files from Google Drive from url list

Tags: download, google-drive, file-download

I have a list of 100 urls that link to files on google drive that I want to download. Each url is like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8asdfasdfasd4YXc/view?usp=sharing

How can I download them all in bulk? Ideally I'd put the urls in a text file and then something would download them all. They are videos

Ok, I can change the urls to this:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[TheFileID]

but I still have the click the "download anyway" button

Comment: Try using WGET.

Comment: I tried it but I get this:

     Resolving drive.google.com (drive.google.com)... 172.217.6.14
     Connecting to drive.google.com       (drive.google.com)|172.217.6.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
view?usp=sharing: No such file or directory

Comment: Ah, are the links open or do they require a logged in user?

Comment: I don't think they require you to be logged in but when you click the download icon upon opening a video in google drive it does give a warning that the file is too big to be scanned by a virus scanner. So maybe you have to go through all that before you can download each video but it would seem like someone has had this problem before and wrote a script to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I found an extension that will open multiple URLs. I changed download settings to not confirm and then I was able to paste a list of URLs in the format [https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[TheFileID]](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=%5BTheFileID%5D) to get them to all download.
Chrome extension called "Open Multiple URLs"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-multiple-urls/oifijhaokejakekmnjmphonojcfkpbbh/related?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

### The steps

1. Install gdown with `pip install gdown` - the command worked in a Standard Windows 11 PowerShell for me. (Make sure You have Python and Pip installed for this command)
2. Make a .txt file with Your links, listed in the following manner:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/someID/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/someotherID/view
and so on - Don't put anything that is not a link here
```

3. Edit the variables at the top in the below script to fit Your needs.
4. Run it
5. If everything goes right - You'll find Your files in the directory You specified

### The Script

```
from os import chdir
from typing import List
from gdown import download
from requests.exceptions import MissingSchema

my_links_file_path: str = r'C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\a\download_links.txt'  # EDIT THIS!
my_output_directory_path: str = r'C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\a'  # EDIT THIS!


def google_drive_bulk_download(links_file_path: str, output_directory_path: str):
    try:
        file = open(links_file_path, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"\n!!! The File '{links_file_path}' is Invalid!\n")
        return

    try:
        chdir(my_output_directory_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"\n!!! The File '{output_directory_path}' is Invalid!\n")
        return

    file_lines: List[str] = [stripped_line for stripped_line in
                             [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
                             if stripped_line]
    file_lines_count: int = len(file_lines)

    print('\n\n==> Started Downloading!\n')

    for i, url_raw in enumerate(file_lines, start=1):
        download_url: str = url_raw.strip()

        print(f'\n-> Downloading... [{i}/{file_lines_count}]')

        try:
            download(url=download_url, quiet=False, fuzzy=True)
        except MissingSchema:
            print(f"!!! The URL '{download_url}' is Invalid!")

        print('Finished!')

    print('\n\n==> Finished Downloading!')


google_drive_bulk_download(my_links_file_path, my_output_directory_path)
```

### The Notes

- This method worked for me. On Windows 11, Python 3.10 and Python 3.11.
- This script may or may not work with other formats of google drive links.
- You may want to try using a VPN if the Downloads fail - I had to.
- There are many browser extensions that help You list the URLs of Your currently open browser tabs. No need to do it by hand.